# Вычисление ряда на языке C

Tags: c, математика, ряды

Всем привет. Есть такое задание:
Вычислить и вывести на экран в виде таблицы значения функции, заданной с помощью ряда, при фиксированном значении x и при разных значениях количества слагаемых n.Количество слагаемых n должно изменяться в цикле от n0 до nm с шагом dN.
Итак, программа должна:

**1)** ввести исходные данные - значения х,n0,nm,dN;

**2)** содержать цикл с управляющей переменной n, изменяющейся от n0 до nm с шагом dN. В теле цикла должны осуществляться следующие действия:

- цикл (внутренний), в теле которого для данных x и n вычисляется по рекуррентной формуле значение суммы ряда;
- расчет «точного» значения суммы по формуле из столбца с заголовком «функция» таблицы 3.1 с вариантами заданий;
- вывод на экран значения n, приближенного и точного значения суммы ряда, ошибки вычисления суммы (разницы между точным и приближенным значением).

[Вот сама таблица с заданием](http://rghost.ru/37090135.view)

А вот код, который мной написан:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main ()
{
    double x, s, v, k, P, y;
    int i, l, n, n0, nm,dn;
    printf("Vvedite x=");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("Vvedite n0=");
    scanf("%d",&n0);
    printf("Vvedite nm=");
    scanf("%d",&nm);
    printf("Vvedite dn=");
    scanf("%d",&dn);
    v=1.0;s=v;l=0; n=n0;
    for (n=n0; n<=nm; n+=dn)
    {
   for (i=1;fabs(v)>0.0001;i++)
    {
        l+=2;
        v *= -(x*x)/(l*(l+1)); s += v;       }
        P=sin(x)/x; 
    y=P-s;
    printf("s=%lf, P=%lf, n=%d, y=%lf\n",s, P, n, y);
   }
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Что-то тут не так. В общем кому не лень--помогите плиз. С меня плюсик =)
Спасибо =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может вот так?

[@altvirus](/users/1086/altvirus) А altvirus -- это не заразно?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main ()
{
    double x, s, v, k, P, y;
    int i, l, n, n0, n1, nm,dn;
    printf("Vvedite x=");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("Vvedite n0=");
    scanf("%d",&n0);
    printf("Vvedite nm=");
    scanf("%d",&nm);
    printf("Vvedite dn=");
    scanf("%d",&dn);
    v=1.0;s=v;l=0; n1=1;
    P=sin(x)/x; 
    for (n=n0; n<=nm; n+=dn) {
        for(;n1 < n; n1++) {
            l+=2;
            v *= -(x*x)/(l*(l+1));
            s += v;
        }
        printf("%3d %10.6g %10.6g %10.6g\n", n1, s, P, s-P);
    }
    return 0;
}
```