# Вычисление суммы ряда. помогите правильно посчитать на языке Си

Tags: c, математика, ряды, формулы

Помогите, пожалуйста, посчитать сумму ряда **(на языке СИ)** с:

1. с указанной точностью "n"
2. с максимально возможной точностью

**Вводятся значения "n" и "x"**. Вот **формула**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай сообщаю, что метку "ряды" я уже смотрел. Если бы мне помогли представленные там задачи, я бы не стал задавать этот вопрос.

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Первый пункт вы решить можете?

Comment: `Если бы мне помогли представленные там задачи` Да там прямо этот же ряд есть.

Comment: @MBo поделитесь ссылкой, пожалуйста, очень удивлюсь, если я и правда не заметил

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, честно говоря, не до конца представляю логику решения

Comment: куча похожих вопросов, попробуйте [Вычисление ряда на языке C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/91032/288358)

Comment: Вы понимаете что написано в формуле, что такое ряд, его сумма, его частичная сумма, как сосчитать частичную сумму?

Comment: [Вот, например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1390923/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисление ряда на языке C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91004/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-c)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нет

Comment: Тогда задавайте конкретные вопросы по конкретным понятиям. Нет смысла решать задачу не понимаю её. Чем вам полезно решение @Harry? Вы можете с ним сделать только одно - сдать преподавателю.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

double sum_n(double x, unsigned int n)
{
    double term = x, sum = x;
    x*=x;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum += term *= -x/(2*i+2)/(2*i+3);
    return sum;
}

double sum(double x)
{
    double term = x, sum = x;
    x*=x;
    for(int i = 0; ; ++i)
    {
        double lsum = sum;
        sum += term *= -x/(2*i+2)/(2*i+3);
        if (lsum == sum) break;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    for(double x = 0; x < 10; x += 0.25)
    {
        printf("%5.2lf  %8.6lf  %8.6lf\n",
               x,sum_n(x,20),sum(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам уже, наверное, можно издавать "АнтиДемидовича" по рядам ;)

Comment: @MBo Да уже такие вещи пишутся со скоростью набора, не думая...